# Find duplicate records with only text case difference

Tags: awk, terminal, grep, duplicates

I have a log file with 8M entries/records with URLs. I'd like to find duplicate URLs (same URLs) with the only difference being their type / text case.

Example:

```
origin-www.example.com/this/is/hard.html
origin-www.example.com/this/is/HARD.html
origin-www.example.com/this/is/Hard.html
```

In this case, there are three duplicates with case sensitivity.

Output should be just the count -c and a new file with the duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the typical `awk '!seen[$0]++' file` trick combined with [`tolower()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) or [`toupper()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) to make all lines be in the same case:

```
$ awk '!seen[tolower($0)]++' file
origin-www.example.com/this/is/hard.html
```

For a different output and counters whatsoever, provide a valid desired output.

Comment: Depending on what exactly means **file with duplicates** here, it could be either:
`$ awk 'seen[tolower($0)]++' input_file > output` to get all non-unique values (without first match)

Comment: yes, i'm trying this right now. Taking forever. It's a 3GB txt file.

Comment: @Marc give a try with a sample file and then see if you like the output. Once you are sure about it, run against the big file.